# Please tell me what this code means

Tags: javascript

can you tell me what this code does as I need to understand it for a coding assessment. I only just started learning JavaScript

```
function getAttackString() {
var foo = "d323b8b34";
var bar = "x334q3j98";
return "The code is: "+(foo.substr(3,foo.length-6))+(bar.substr(2));
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: you should check out the MDN Docs for this stuff - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: Amazingly this _exact same_ question was asked a couple of weeks ago...

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking up what .length and .substr are.

For example, what will foo.length give you? A good way to find out would be:

```
var x = "abc123";
console.log(x.length);
```

`console.log` is a command to print information to your web browser console, very helpful when doing debugging work.